# form validation on submit

Tags: forms, validation

I am facing problem in form validation. Following is my jQuery validation code.

kindly help me how this validation is working on submit button.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".col a").click(function() {
        $(".col a").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
        });
    });

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery(".expContent").hide();
        //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
        jQuery(".expHeading").click(function() {
            jQuery(this).next(".expContent").slideToggle(500);
        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Vertical
        $("#vertical").on("blur", function(e) {
        if ($("#vertical").val().length < 2) {
            alert("vertical", "Vertical is Mandatory");
        } else {
            hideMsg("vertical");
        }
        });
        // Name
        $("#name").on("blur", function(e) {
        if ($("#name").val().length < 2) {
            alert("Name is Mandatory");
        } else {
            hideMsg("name");
        }
        });

        function IsEmail(email) {
        var filter = /^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$/;
        if (filter.test(email)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        }
        $("#email").on("blur", function(e) {
        if ($("#email").val().length == 0) {
            //alert("Please submit a Valid Email Id");
        }
        if (IsEmail($("#email").val())) {
            hideMsg("email");
        } else {
            alert("Please submit a Valid Email Id");
        }
        });
        // Mobile No
        $("#enqMobileNo").on("blur", function(e) {
        if ($("#enqCountryResidence").val() == "in") {
        if ($("#enqMobileNo").val().length == 10) {
            hideMsg("enqMobileNo");
        } else {
            alert('Please Enter 10 Digit Mobile No. Only like 9812345678. Without Area or Country Code i.e "0" or "+91"');
        }
        } else {
        if ($("#enqMobileNo").val().length 1) {
            hideMsg("enqMobileNo");
        } else {
            alert("Please Enter Mobile No. Only. Without Area or Country Code");
        }
        }
        });
        $("#enqMobileNo").on('keyup', function() {
        if ($("#enqMobileNo").val() == "0") {
            $("#enqMobileNo").val("");
        }
        if ($("#enqCountryResidence").val() == "in") {
            limitText(this, 10);
        if ($("#enqMobileNo").val().length == 10) {
            hideMsg("enqMobileNo");
        }
        } else {
            //inlineMsg
            ("enqMobileNo", "Please Enter Mobile No. Only<br /Without Area or Country Code");
        }
        });
        // Gender
        $("#gender").on("blur", function(e) {
        if ($("#gender").val() == "") {
            alert('Please select Gender', 2);
        } else {
            hideMsg("gender");
        }
        });
        // Age 
        $("#age").on("blur", function(e) {
        if ($("#age").val() == "") {
            alert('Please select Age', 2);
        } else {
            hideMsg("age");
        }
        });

        // City 
        $("#enqCity").on("blur", function(e) {
        if ($("#enqCity").val() == "") {
            alert('Current Location City Name is Mandatory', 2);
        } else {
            hideMsg("enqCity");
        }
        });

        // Course
        $("#enqSection").on("blur", function(e) {
        if ($("#enqSection").val() == "") {
            alert('Please Select Course', 2);
        } else {
            hideMsg("enqSection");
        }
        });

        // Spl
        $("#enqSpeciality").on("blur", function(e) {
        if ($("#enqSpeciality").val() == "") {
            alert('Please Select Speciality', 2);
        } else {
            hideMsg("enqSpeciality");
        }
        });

        // Level 
        $("#enqLevel").on("blur", function(e) {
        if ($("#enqLevel").val() == "") {
            alert('Please Select Level', 2);
        } else {
            hideMsg("enqLevel");
        }
        });

        function limitText(field, maxChar) {
        var ref = $(field),
        val = ref.val();
        if (val.length = maxChar) {
            ref.val(function() {
            console.log(val.substr(0, maxChar))
            return val.substr(0, maxChar);
        });
        }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is better to use [jQuery form validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/). It is very easy to use.You can get step by step help with examples [on this site](http://www.webtips4u.com/html5-form-validation-using-jquery-form-validation-plugin/)